# Unable to see Facebook news.read action story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to publish an open graph story using common read action. I added the read(news) action in the Action Types. Then I got the code for creating a read action as

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads? access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
>   method=POST& article=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F434264856596891

I **used facebook graph explorer** for posting a story like `Anubhav read an article on XXXX`. 
by calling the user /me/news.reads with the params article = article_url. It gets publishd and I get a response id

I can see it in my activity log, but when I click on the link of the post, it redirects me to a broken link url. I am unable to figure out why I am being redirected to the broken link, and how can I correct it ?

**EDIT**

How I posted the request using graph explorer . I went to this [url](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/310004301204/). I change the request type to POST. And in the field wrote /me/news.reads.

Added a field article with [url](http://www.mygola.com/4-day-trip-to-new-york/q24770) . I got a response {id:684883751555542}. When I clicked on the [link of activity](https://www.facebook.com/anubhav1617/activity/684883751555542) on my activity log, I see a broken page link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you did a GET request instead of a post (from the URL you're showing)? If I follow the description given under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/news.reads/ and do a POST request with the article as form parameter, it works.

I had to "unescape" the URL though, maybe you can try this?

Comment: nopes I made a post request using thr facebook graph explorer.

Comment: Well, the URL you've shown is not a Graph API Explorer URL imho. Can you post the original and the "broken" link as well so that we can see waht's the difference?

Comment: I have updated my question, if I can provide some more things please help

Comment: Tried it as you described, works perfectly. Make sure that you chose the appropriate app in the app selection box in the upper right corner.